# Stream API not sending the "to" attribute

Tags: getstream-io

I am integrating the Getstream.io in my Blog application. I want to Update the Users who are following the Current user(user who is posting a blog). I am passing the target user also but when the Stream API sending me response there is no "to" attribute. What to do ?

When I am trying access the user feed It's sending me the response Activity of the logged in user.
feeds = feed_manager.get_user_feed(user.id)

But When I am trying access the followers feed nothing is returning.
feed = feed_manager.get_news_feeds(request.user.id)['timeline']

What is the issue? Please help.

This is the Blog model;

class Blog(activity.Activity, CommonFields):
    blog_owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='blog_owner')
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

```
blogger = models.ForeignKey('blogger.Blogger',null=True)
blog_favourites = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                         related_name='blog_favourite')
# comments = TreeForeignKey(BComment, null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)
blog_followers = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='blog_follower')
blog_likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='blog_like')
blog_group_handle = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='blog_group')
blog_views = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='blog_view')
slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True,max_length=600)
is_external_blog=models.BooleanField(default=False)
feeds = BlogManager()
objects = models.Manager()

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-updated_at']

@property
def activity_notify(self):
    targets = []
    ''' The followers of the blog_owner '''
    # target_user =Profile.objects.only('target_id').get(user_id=self.user.id).target_id
    for user in self.parse_mentions():
        targets.append(feed_manager.get_news_feeds(user.id)['flat'])
    return targets
```

Comment: Better if you add some code as well ;)

Comment: I have shared the Blog model. I wants to send the notification to the users who are following the blog_owner(The current user who posting the blog).

Comment: this line "targets.append(feed_manager.get_news_feeds(user.id)['flat'])" is sending the activity to the flat feed and not to the timeline.